# jQuery, change source to animate the rotation of a line. faster alternatives?

Tags: ajax, image, rotation

I am making digital instruments for a car. These instruments will be constantly updated by information through ajax. These instruments will be served from a server onboard the vehicle through WLAN (fast) to my iPhone 3G. Is imperative to the success of the project that the updating of the tachometer is smooth and very responsive. Otherwise, it will look retarded.

The first problem I encountered was when I made this demo where tachometer moves quickly back and forth between zero and a thousand RPM: http://www.kingoslo.com/instruments/ **When viewed on my iPhone 3G, the arrow simply doesn't move back and forth smoothly enough.**

This javascript works by changing the source of the arrow img-element (which is semi transparant {4 color png} floating on top the static picture of the scale {16 color png}, by the way).

I've been made aware of new image editing features in HTML5, and wondered if any of those, or any other methods will be more responsive. Also, I am getting an iPhone 4 for xmas, so that may be a bit faster, but I've got the feeling that it still will fall short for the current build, especially when I add the constant ajax updating that is required to keep the instruments change values as the driver drives along.

Thank you for your time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

I think using `canvas` will result in much faster animation - it was created to handle drawing, whilst manipulating DOM elements is comparably expensive.

Mobile Safari is compatible with `canvas`.

Alternatively, you could try incorporating all the angles as one large [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), and then just manipulating its `background-position` CSS property (`element.style.backgroundPosition` in the JavaScript DOM API).